# Javascript debugging in Safari web browser

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari

I have a JavaScript error in my web project, and this error appears only in Safari 5 web browser. And the problem is Safari says just error message, but not file and line where this error appears. So, I can't find which code cause this error. Does anybody know how can I find code line causes this error?

Here is shot with debugger. 
[image: Debugger screenshot]
http://xmages.net/storage/10/1/0/d/c/upload/691ce801.png

Thanks for helping.

Comment: the error message suggests that it's in a string that has been passed to the `eval()` function, hence no line number.

Comment: In this case it looks like it happens inside some jQuery code.

Comment: more likely in one of those third party plugins.  Just search for that line of text in the source, there's unlikely to be many occurrences.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was jquery.tmpl plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the "stop sign" icon until it turns blue and then rerun the code. This should make the debugger halt on the line that generated the exception (and allow you to inspect the local variables and execution stack at that point).

Comment: I was clicking, but nothing happen.

Comment: Are you sure you clicked the correct button? I was talking about the 8-sided button on the lower left, next to the curly braces that reindent the code,

Comment: Aha... Yeah, I was clicking wrong button. :) Thanks, next time I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping!

Problem resolved now. It was jQuery template plugin. It causes this error when some DOM element in template has ID same as template variable name.
E. G.

```
var template = "<div id="foo">${foo}</div>"
var data = {foo: "bar"}
$.tmpl(template, data)
```

Solution: Rename ID of template variable name.

```
var template = "<div id="foo">${bar}</div>"
var data = {bar: "bar"}
$.tmpl(template, data)
```